# Django: Download file after fetching file from S3

Tags: python, django, amazon-s3, boto3

I have files stored in S3 that I wish to serve to the client when they click a link/button.

```
file_path = '/tmp/' + attachment.file_name
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
s3.meta.client.download_file(
    settings.S3_BUCKET,
    attachment.key, file_path)

if os.path.exists(file_path):
    with open(file_path, 'rb') as fh:
        response = HttpResponse(
            fh.read(), content_type="application/force-download")
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=' + attachment.file_name
        return response
```

Ajax request to get the file on button click.

```
function downloadAttachment(attachment_id){
    $.ajax({
        url: '/download-attachment/',
        method: 'get',
        data: {
            attachment_id,
        },
    });
};
```

But when the request is done the file doesn't download. When I look at the network response and open the response on a new tab, it downloads the file. How do I implement this, so when click the link/button the file gets downloaded right away at the current page.